# How to repeat a cell a number of times if it meets a specific criteria and then returns to normal?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have data in an Excel worksheet. 
Specifically, I have data in Columns `D` and `E` (and some others). 
I want to fill in Columns `F` and `G` with a formula,
using the data from Columns `D` and `E`. 
The rules are:

- Usually, `Fn` should be
  the same as `Dn`.
- If `Dn` is "Depression" or "Hyperinflation",
  then `F(n+1)`, `F(n+2)`
  and `F(n+3)` should be "Depression"
  (i.e., "Depression" will be repeated for the next three cells),
  and `D(n+1)`, `D(n+2)`
  and `D(n+3)` should be ignored.
  Note: some text values have trailing spaces,
  and therefore `TRIM()` is needed.
- `G` should be derived from `E` following the same rules.

The second bullet hides a subtle pitfall. 
Consider these data:

| Row | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 59 | Depression | blah59 | Depression | blah59 |
| 60 | Above average | blah60 | Depression | blah60 |
| 61 | Depression | blah61 | Depression | blah61 |
| 62 | Average | blah62 | Depression | blah62 |
| 63 | Average | blah63 | Average | blah63 |
| 64 | Above average | blah64 | Above average | blah64 |

`F59` is "Depression" because it's the same as `D59`. 
But, since `D59` is "Depression",
`F60`, `F61` and `F62` are also set to "Depression",
and `D60`, `D61` and `D62` are are ignored. 
Specifically, we ignore the fact that `D61` is also "Depression",
and therefore we don't set `F63` and `F64` to "Depression",
but rather leave them equal to `D63` and `D64`.

Some of the answers that have been posted (incorrectly)
set `F63` and `F64` to "Depression".

---

Edited:

How would you fix it if it's "Hyperinflation", "Hyperinflation" or "Depression","Hyperinflation" in column D?

"Hyperinflation", "Hyperinflation" worksheet:
[image: Excel Worksheet]

What I would like it to look like:
[image: Excel Worksheet]

"Depression","Hyperinflation" Worksheet:
[image: Excel Worksheet]

What I would like it to look like:
[image: Excel Worksheet]

So in column D, if the cell is "Hyperinflation" or "Depression", and within the next three cells there is another "Hyperinflation" or "Depression", I would not want to repeat them in column F. So the "Hyperinflation" or "Inflation" within the next three cells in column D would be ignored.

Dropbox Link: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/wxfzk0r320wm57r7jge5b/PART-B.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=z407ft00oi9e0i4m9qlvmmirh

Comment: This is a complex question and you are asking your volunteer fellow users for help. You could help them help you by saving a worksheet like those shown in DropBox or OneDrive and posting a view link here. It should contain all of the possible combinations you are asking about, clearly labelled.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have attached the Dropbox link in my post now.

Comment: (1) Please don't just add more data and say things like "Here's what my worksheet looks like ***now***" and "Here are the results I want ***now***"; that forces people to get out their magnifying glasses again and look at your data *again.*  Use words, like "I tried ZygD's answer, and it's a good start, but it doesn't quite do what I want.  It does *\_\_X\_\_,* and I want *\_\_Y\_\_.*"  And you didn't need to add two more images; you could have just directed the readers' attention to rows 59 through 64 of your original data; they already illustrate the issue. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (2) Thanks for posting the Dropbox link.  Unfortunately, the data in that file don't seem to clearly match the rules you described.  (3) It would have been nice if you had said that some of your data have trailing spaces, and that therefore ```TRIM()``` is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that it is impossible to do what the question asks for
with a closed-form, single-cell formula. 
Consider the following hypothetical data,
with the corresponding desired results (as I understand the requirements):

| Row | D |  | F |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 72 | ant |  | ant |  |
| 73 | bat |  | bat |  |
| 74 | cat |  | cat |  |
| 75 | dog |  | dog |  |
| 76 | Depression | ← | Depression | ← |
| 77 | illustration |  | Depression | ← |
| 78 | jackpot |  | Depression | ← |
| 79 | Depression | ⇐ | Depression | ← |
| 80 | kangaroo |  | kangaroo |  |
| 81 | leopard |  | leopard |  |
| 82 | Depression | ← | Depression | ← |
| 83 | melody |  | Depression | ← |
| 84 | nighthawk |  | Depression | ← |
| 85 | Depression | ⇐ | Depression | ← |
| 86 | orange |  | orange |  |
| 87 | purple |  | purple |  |

There's no local difference between Rows 83 & 84 and Rows 86 & 87. 
I believe it's impossible for a formula in Column `F` (or `G`) to distinguish
between those cases without looking at the entire `D` column.

Luckily, it seems to be fairly easy with helper columns. 
Pick two columns that you aren't using. 
They can be `H` and `I`, `Y` and `Z`, `AF` and `AG`, or whatever you want. 
I'll assume that you choose `H` and `I`.

Assuming that your data start in Row 15 (as your question shows)
and that cells `H14` and `I14` are empty (which should be the case,
since I've assumed that you aren't using the helper columns), enter

```
=IF(AND(H14>0,H14<4), H14+1, --OR(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(D15, CHAR(160), " "))="Depression",TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(D15, CHAR(160), " "))="Hyperinflation"))
```

into cell `H15`, and enter

```
=IF(H15>1, "Depression", TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(D15, CHAR(160), " ")))
```

into cell `F15`. 
Copy `F` into `G` and `H` into `I`, and drag/fill down.

The value in the helper column is "normally" 0. 
When `H(n-1)` is 0, `Hn`
is set to `--OR(D15="Depression",D15="Hyperinflation")`
(the final part of the `IF` expression). 
We use `TRIM()` because the data in your file have trailing spaces,
which cause the string comparison to fail. 
We use `SUBSTITUTE(cell, CHAR(160), " ")`
because the data in your file have trailing ***non-breaking** spaces,*
which `TRIM()` doesn't handle,
so we have to convert those to regular spaces before calling `TRIM()`. 
This `OR` expression is `TRUE` if `Dn`
is equal to one of the two trigger words, and `FALSE` otherwise. 
The `--` turns these into 1 and 0. 
A value of 1 indicates that this is the first row of a repeat block;
a 0 indicates that it is another normal row.

If `H(n-1)` is positive but less than 4, that indicates
that Row *n-1* is part of a repeat block (but not the last row),
and so Row *n* must be part of a repeat block (but not the first row). 
So we add 1 (the middle part of the `IF` expression),
to denote that Row *n* is the 2nd, 3rd or 4th row
of a repeat block. 
If `H(n-1)` is 4, we go back to
setting `Hn` based on `Dn`.

The formula for column `F` says that if Row *n* is the 2nd, 3rd or 4th row
of a repeat block, `Fn` is set to "Depression";
otherwise, it is set equal to `Dn`.